# SVG doesn't work in IE and safari when used with SVG Sprites.

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, safari

I am using SVG Sprites to add svg icons on my page. There is no issue in Chrome and Firefox but i am not able to see any of the svg icons in IE and Safari.

```
<div class="toggle-icons">
<span class="toggle-rows active">
<svg class="icon"  >
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" link:href="icons.svg#icon-photo-row"></use>
</svg>
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="row"> 
</span>
<span class="toggle-grid">
<svg class="icon"  >
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-photo-grid"></use>
</svg>        
<input type="radio" name="toggle" value="grid">
</span>
</div>
```

icons.svg looks something like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<symbol id="icon-photo-row" viewBox="0 0 19.983 11.084">
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="0.375" x2="3.75" y2="0.375"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.292" y1="0.375" x2="19.983" y2="0.375"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="5.542" x2="3.75" y2="5.542"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.292" y1="5.542" x2="19.983" y2="5.542"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="0" y1="10.709" x2="3.75" y2="10.709"/>
<line fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="7.292" y1="10.709" x2="19.983" y2="10.709"/>
</symbol>

<symbol id="icon-photo-grid" viewBox="0 0 18.28 18.271">
<rect x="0.375" y="0.375" fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="7.409" height="7.411"/>
<rect x="10.493" y="0.375" fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="7.412" height="7.411"/>
<rect x="0.375" y="10.488" fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="7.409" height="7.408"/>
<rect x="10.493" y="10.488" fill="none" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="7.412" height="7.408"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle-icons svg.icon {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  fill: #bfbfbf;
  stroke: #4D5E68;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.toggle-icons span.active svg.icon {
  fill: #95a1aa;
}
```

Can anyone explain why is there a problem in rendering the SVG's on IE and Safari and what might be the fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IE are you using? (older versions didn't support SVG). And even if it is a recent version, have you checked that it isn't in running compatibility mode? (which would disable support for SVG)

Comment: Ditto Safari....Safari for Windows stopped at v5.1 and may have issues with SVG.

Comment: IE doesn't support external `use` according to [**CanIuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) - See known Issues...there is a polyfull linked

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. I used the [SVG4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) and now it's working on safari and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) solved the problem. Now it's visible on IE as well as Safari.

Answer (score 3):

svg4everybody uses requestAnimationFrame, which causes too many calls. So I wrote a simple and lighweight polyfill that fetches and caches external SVGs referenced in <use> elements when the browser itself fails to do so. This polyfill uses feature detection rather than browser sniffing. It's on github: https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse

Live demo: https://icomoon.io/svgxuse-demo